# CSS Border corner radius

Tags: css, border

how can I replicate this?

[image: Border radius]
I need to do this with CSS, but I only can do the outside part with 2 separate lines:

```css
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: 4rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 150px;
}

.left-top {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left"></div>
<div class="left-top"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with one element and some gradient but without transparency:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:20px;
  padding:5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box,
    linear-gradient(red,red)       top left    /60px 40px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)     top right   /60px 40px,
    linear-gradient(green,green)   bottom left /60px 40px,
    linear-gradient(purple,purple) bottom right/60px 40px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, one more question. Why the content-box? what does it do?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-backgound-clip-property-and-use-cases/ this link mighthelp understand that content-box part.

Comment: @FábioFernandes to only color the background considering the content and not the padding. it's the trick to show only the part of the other gradient on the 5px padding. Change the white color with a transparent one and you will better understand